# Openstack: Allocate more memory per guest

Tags: virtualization, openstack, nova

I have setup openstack using this guide: http://ubuntu-cloud-installer.readthe...

I am able to create multiple instances with the m1.small flavor which uses 2 GB ram, but when I try to create an instance with any more ram it fails. When I try to create the instance in Horizon it gives the error:

"Error: Failed to launch instance "test": Please try again later [Error: No valid host was found. Exceeded max scheduling attempts 3 for instance 39f73c98-0b77-4613-a13d-244c357efb55. Last exception: [u'Traceback (most recent call last):\n', u' File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2039, in _do]."

Looking at the nova-conductor.log I have the error:

"internal error: process exited while connnecting to monitor: Cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram': Cannot allocate memory"

I am assuming that I need to allow the virtulization to give each guest more than 2 gb ram, but I just do not know where to start setting that up.

The server has 250GB ram and is only to be used for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that the installation installs openstack in LXC, and in that container a VM is created for the compute node using libvirt, and this VM only had 4GB memory.
I was able to expand it using this guide http://earlruby.org/2014/05/increase-a-vms-available-memory-with-virsh/